# Error handling from Internal API calls in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a controller where I make internal API calls. The happy case is fine, but I want to make an ErrorHandling page/component to handle errors. Since I am a beginner at Angular I do not know the best way to do it. Currently, I am doing it by alerting the user with the required error message.

CoreController.js

```
...
function getItems(id){
    Service.getItemsByCartId(
        vm.currencyCode,
        id
    ).then(function (response) {
        //Happy Case
    }).catch(function (error) {
        alert(error.status, error);
    });
}
```

How do I handle the error case, I want to display it as a separate page. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Since there can be many HTTP error status returned, I need to handle them all seperatley.
4XX error occurred -> I should show reason as Session expired please refresh browser

5XX error occurred -> You should show reason as XXX  & have option to show error logs for user

Comment: do you want to display error at different page or modal or toast please explain? or you just want to manage all errors from single component

Comment: What do you suggest is a best practice? I am considering a modal?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a service called ApiService. In this service you can write following function **POST, PUT, DELETE, GET** and this function will accept body as params that you want to use for API request.

Then write another function say like **handleError** and this function will accept error params from POST, PUT, DELETE or GET function. This **handleError** function will traverse the error format that you will get from server and show this error to the **Modal**.

From **Controller** you will call this POST, PUT, DELETE, GET service for API request with body params.

This way you can handle error from central service for whole application. Besides,
you can write **interceptor** from where all server calls handled so you can handle error from interceptor as well.